# How run a java webservice made in eclipse run on the apache server in xampp?

Tags: c#, java, android, web-services, xampp

I have a webservice which I made in eclipse. But this webservice should not run on the tomcat server from eclipse. It should run on the apache server from xampp. This xampp is located on a Virtual Machine.

But I have no idea how to include this webservice to the xampp apasche server.

Has anyone an idea how to do that?

Comment: apache httpd can't run java services, unless you want to run the thing in CGI mode and fire up a JVM for every request. That's why there's tomcat.

Comment: hm ok. and can I run it on the tomcat of xampp?

Comment: No. You either run tomcat, or you run httpd. You can't have both binding to port 80 of the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP isn't a Java environment, and you have to have one to run a Java service. You can run a container like Tomcat or Jetty, or you can use an environment like Spring Boot that creates an internal Web server component.

Comment: ok. i'm sorry I'm really new to this webservice topic. How can I run my Webservice on this VM with xampp on it. I have an external IP address and its located to the localhost of this VM and from there the webservice should run.

Comment: @silvia_aut Probably best to close and reask your question, then. The best approach is usually just to install a Java container like Tomcat and run your application in it. More recently, I've been using Spring Boot and having my whole application run as a regular Java program that happens to listen for HTTP connections, but that's only really suitable for Spring projects.